# Поиск кнопок по title swift 3.0 xcode

Tags: swift, swift3, uibutton

Добрый день.
Делаю игру. Необходимо при прохождении уровня, включать кнопку, по стандарту она выключена (enable = false).
Title у кнопок от 1 до 12(то есть 12 кнопок). У меня есть переменная, которая содержить информацию о том, где остановился пользователь.
Я подумал, что можно написать цикл, который бы открывал все прошедшие уровни(кнопки становились enable = true)
То есть
       i = 1
       От i до {кол-во пройденных уровней} делать
          кнопка.имякнопки(интВСтроку(i)) = enable
       закончить

В процессе реализации возникли проблемы. Не хватает опыта написать просто цикл. Прошу помощи.

Цикл в ViewController
Кнопки в Main.storyboard

Comment: покажите что уже написали

Comment: Спасибо что ответили. Я уже сам разобрался.

Comment: либо публикуйте свой ответ, либо удаляйте вопрос

Comment: Ну так я опубликовал

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Кусок кода, который я не мог написать.

```
//это объявление нужно, чтобы сделать их кликабельными/не кликабельными
@IBOutlet var buttonEnable: [UIButton]!

override func viewDidLoad() {

    //все кнопки перехода уровня до топ сцены делаем кликабельными
    for _ in 1...topScene {
        let button = buttonEnable.removeFirst()
        button.isEnabled = true
    }

}
```